# ¿Como puedo mostrar mas de 100 resultados por página?

Tags: scraping, table

Quiero cambiar el numero de resultados de esta página: `https://fifatracker.net/players/` a mas de 100 para luego exportar la tabla a Excel y que me sea mucho mas sencillo. Si hay una manera de extraer la tabla de todas las paginas tambien me serviria, gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! E intentaste algo? porque asi, parece que quisieras que hicieran todo el trabajo por vos...

Comment: Puedes intentar haciendo un script que recorra cada página hasta https://fifatracker.net/players/?page=382